# Unable to fetch content from CollegeBoard using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, web-scraping, dynamic-content

https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/dickinson-college

**I was trying to fetch the content of this page using PHP's `preg_match` function:**

```
$filename = 'https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/dickinson-college';
$content = file_get_contents($filename);

$subject = $content;
$pattern = '#(?<=<span class="locality" itemprop="addressLocality">)(\w*)(?=<\/span>)#';
preg_match($pattern,$subject,$city);

print_r($city);
```

The info that I want to fetch is within the div with class "clearfix margin60 marginBottomOnly".

When using Firebug or 'Inspect Element' in Chrome, the content within this div is visible. 
However when I viewed the page source, the div is empty.

Could anybody tell me the reason and how to get the content that I want from the page (for e.g., the location of the school)?

Comment: You practicing regexp and you need to do it this way? Its a lot easier to get html content with DOMDocument

Comment: Can you recommend me some resources to read more about how I could get HTML content with DOMDocument?

Comment: a lot of information you can find even here, on stack, but if you want to work fast and easy, personally i use simplehtmldom,, check it: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

You don`t see it because the content is generated by JavaScript function, if u will check "script" tab and look for the div name [ gwtDiv ], you will what script is generating it,